# asterisk on vmware

Tags: vmware, asterisk, vmware-workstation

I am having trouble installing asterisk in a vmware workstation. My host is WindowsXP.
The OS (CENTOS) is installed but the asterisk rpms are not installed.

Does it ring a bell? Has anyone completed successfully this task?

Comment: I don't get errors. Only CentOS is installed. I don't know why the rest of the installation is not completed. I reached a screen that prompts me for username and password

Comment: It sounds to me like that is the login prompt for CentOS.  CentOS is another operating system entirely, and so you need to log in to it.  You should have been asked for a "root" password.
Use username "root" and then enter your password when prompted.  From there, you should be able to follow the instructions at http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/yum and you'll have a "bare" Asterisk install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to log you in CentOs and run a terminal ?

If yes, have you launch the rpm -i command ? Did it returns errors ?

Comment: I can log in and I have no problem running rpm -i or rpm -qa to list all rpms

Comment: On CentOs you can also install Asterisk through Yum, another package manager. It's explain here : http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/yum

If you really want to use RPM, you can get it from zultron here : http://www.zultron.com/2009/03/asterisk-rpms/

Answer (score 1):

why you bother so much for asterisk rpm file, and centos , grab an vicidial ISO file or go auto dial file which is precompiled with CENTOS.

find a better source for the asterisk,

http://www.vicibox.com/

http://www.vicidial.com/

http://goautodial.org/attachments/download/397/goautodial-ce-2.1-final.iso.html

http://ratan.com.np/soft_s/VicidialNow_CE_1.1.rar

Try using Speed Bit or Orbit downloader ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you haven't tried installing asterisk from sources. It's just a matter of configure, make and make install. You can also get a complete frontend (FreePBX) by following their tutorial at http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/installation/install-process-for-centos-5-1